USB not showing in Files sidebar
I have a USB stick inserted in my Ubuntu 24.04 laptop. There are two Ventoy OSes on it now. I want to add another one but first want to update Ventoy to the latest version. After downloading the update I saw in the Files sidebar the USB with the two OSes. I wasn't sure if the Ventoy update had been installed on the USB, but meanwhile downloaded the operating system. When I went back to Files I didn't see the USB drive in the sidebar anymore. I can't find it anywhere. I've been told I shouldn't remove the stick from the laptop until I see on the popup window that it's safe to do so. I don't know where to find what the status of that USB is. I can't take the laptop anywhere with the stick in it. Any advice?

run Disks utility on your PC to see if the USB stick is listed. If it is, click on the square icon to the left of the cogwheel icon to umount it. Other than that, I just tried pulling the stick out (on my scratch PC) without unmounting then rebooting the pc the PC and reinserting the stick. It worked fine, appeared on the desktop and listed the files.

You don't say what steps you took to upgrade your Ventoy USB but this video seems quite helpful

@graham I opened Disks and saw the USB drive. I clicked on the unmount button and extracted it. When I reinserted it, it was showing in the sidebar with the two operating systems still there. Thanks for showing me where it was. As for Ventoy, I'm having trouble following the directions in the video from your link and other places. On my screen I don't see the window they show for clicking on the update button. I've downloaded ventoy-1.0.99-linux.tar.gz several times, and clicked on extract, but I don't know what else I should do. Do you know where I can find more detailed instructions? Thanks.

Glad that worked for you. I've found this video which is more Linux specific and also this ByteBiteBit article which might also help.
